# 5x5 Bingo Puzzle (odds)

Tags: combinations, puzzle

I have a question that is very similar to this one [5x5 Bingo Puzzle [Logical thinking problem]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798161/5x5-bingo-puzzle-logical-thinking-problem).

5 people participate in a custom game. They are given blank cards, in which they have to fill numbers from 1-25 in a 5x5 table. Each card must contain all the numbers from 1-25 without repetition. The host of the game, then calls out the numbers randomly (between 1-25, without repetition). After each call from the host, the players have to scratch the called out number from their respective cards.The first person to complete a row of 5 scratched out numbers (diagonal, vertical and horizontal rows count) wins the game. What are the chances of 1 person getting 5 rows after first 16 numbers have been called? And what strategy would people use if they mutually want 1(anyone) of them to get 5 rows in first 16 numbers? 
Sorry, if ive described it poorly. Not a native speaker

Comment: Do you mean get a row of $5$ scratched-out numbers?

Comment: Sorry, i meant 5 rows of 5 scratched out numbers.