# How to find top 3

Tags: computational-mathematics

If i have 25 horses in one race you can tack 5 horse only, if you want find top 3 horse from this 25 horses than how many race you need for find top 3 horse from it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Will each race give the same result?

Comment: Ya but at the end you find 3 top horse ?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- How many races of five runners do you need to find the fastest horse overall of $25$?
- How many of the remaining $24$ horses could possibly be the second and third fastest overall?

Comment: Actually i want top 3 horse from 25 so how many  race i need to do for find 3 top horse but in one race only 5 horse can take part

Comment: I know what you want.  Can you answer my hints before this question is closed as a duplicate, for example of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744473/horse-race-question-how-to-find-the-3-fastest-horses or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361065/why-6-races-are-not-sufficient-in-the-25-horses-5-tracks-problem ?

Comment: Ya not exactly but similarly question but it's question is totally different from that question

Comment: Guys i found that answer its 11

Comment: That seems too many given the answers in the linked questions